# Need help removing a space during XSLT transformation

Tags: xslt, transformation, removing-whitespace

The unknown processing instruction(s) are causing spaces due to the line ending.

XML input

```
trust.<footnote id="a0r5t3y0h2" origin.id="a0r5r3y3r1"><?unknown page=A-5?>
<footnote.marker><superior>39</superior></footnote.marker><footnote.text><para id="a0r5t3y0h3" origin.id="a0r5r3y3r2">Restatement
```

HTML output

```
trust.
<sup>39</sup><span class="footnote" id="$footnote_counter" style="white-space:normal"><span data-ein-anchor="a0r5t3y0h3">Restatement
```

There should never be any white space between the last character and the sup tag.

How can I make this happen?

Tried using the normalize function in different ways but could not get it to work.

If I move the footnote.marker tag up one line the space dose not occur so I know this is what is causing the problem.

Do not have much control over the xml files I receive.

Still learning XSLT and anything would help. Tried searching this and other sites.

Comment: Do you have any XSLT to show as well? What is the `xsl:output indent` set to?

Comment: Hard to tell with such a minimal (not well-formed even) XML snippet and no XSLT. Are you using `xsl:strip-space` at all? If not, try adding `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`  as a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet`. (Or maybe change `*` to `footnote` until you can make sure that no wanted spaces get stripped. You might need to also use an `xsl:preserve-space`.)

Comment: <xsl:strip-space elements="footnote"/>

Comment: I added -<xsl:strip-space elements="footnote"/> - and that seems to have done the trick. Need to check the rest of the document for any unwanted changes. Thanks Daniel. Martin here is want you asked about - <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>. Sorry for the minimal post but I get confused with some of these giant post and I figured this should be easy. Once again Thanks to both of you  for responding.